# Show that $(2proj_v-I)^T(2proj_v-I)=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

So we have that $(2proj_v-I)^T(2proj_v-I)=I$

Working on the left-hand side we have:

$$(2proj_v^T-I^T)(2proj_v-I)$$

Multiplying through we have:

$$(2proj_v^T)(2proj_v)-2Iproj_v+I$$

But I don't know how to simplify this so that I just get $I$. Have I made a mistake somewhere else with the transpose?

Comment: @daw $proj_v$ represents a projection about a hyperplane $v$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: Are you saying that $(2x-1)(2x-1)=(2x)(2x)-2x+1$?!

Answer (score 2):

Let me denote $P:=proj_v$. I assume that $P$ is an orthogonal projection, thus $P^2 = P$ and $P=P^T$. Then one can prove
$$
(2 P-I)^T(2 P-I)= 4 P^TP - 2 P - 2 P^T  + I = 4 P - 2P - 2P + I = I.
$$
It seems that the term $-2P^T$ is missing in your calculation.